# How to write off taxes when returning the pre-tax amount of sign on bonus because the company refused to send corrected W2?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, bonus

I received a sign on bonus which was included on the 2019 W2 from the company. But I quit on May 1st, 2020 and wrote them a check of the total pre-tax amount of the sign on bonus to return the money. This was because the company said they never send a corrected W2 and they gave me a letter to show IRS as proof of me returning the pre-tax amount of sign on bonus.

Now, I am about to file my income tax for 2019 but I don't know how (where to) put this since I don't have a corrected W2. What should I do? Thank you.